# display contents of `<details>` when `<summary>` is closed

Tags: css

Is there a way to display the content of a `<details>` element even when it is collapsed?

I'd like to style the contents of the `<details>` element differently depending on whether it has the `open` attribute.

Below is an example of the type of thing I'm trying to accomplish. I'd like the text to be clipped when the `<details>` element is collapsed, but grow to show all its content when expanded. (The exact implementation of clipping text and expanding content here is irrelevant. The important part is simply getting the `<p>` tag to display when the `<details>` is collapsed.)

```css
details[open] p {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

details:not([open]) p {
  display:       inline;
  max-height:    3em;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>This is the summary element.</summary>
  <p>This is the details element.</p>
</details>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's nothing you can do to make the content show up. The reason is the internal implementation of the `details` element:

[image: details element user agent shadow DOM]

As you can see, the content is being hidden via setting the internal `slot` via inline style to `display: none;`.

As you can neither access the shadow root via Javascript, nor can you target any element via outside CSS rules, there's nothing you can do here.

Comment: That sucks. Would have been a great way to standardise "Spoiler" text in game/fiction discussions or "NSFW" content ... anywhere.